# Android Service for getting gps location updates

Tags: android, android-studio, service

I have been working with gps from last few weeks, and successfully created a working Service that gives the location updates and sends it to the server as I had planed. But still there are some issues with it.

More about the service:
The Service is started from
1) an activity
2) when the boot process completed
3) even when the gps status is changed (i.e. enabled or disabled)

I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` for doing this.

Now the issue with this structure is:
     on first time after install the gps is not enabled and the app is running. Here the first time I start my service. So after starting the service it works fine. Now if I press home button and remove the app from the recent activity tray the service gives the location updates even the interval for the next location update is not completed ( location update interval is set with the instance of LocationManager with time as 1000 ms and distance as 300 meter

rest of the time when ever the app gps state changed or the reboot is performed the service is working as it has to expects.

SO WHAT IS EXACTLY HAPPENING WHEN THE APP IS REMOVED FROM THE RECENT ACTIVITY TRAY AND WHY THE UPDATES ARE GIVEN BY THE GPS EVEN THE UPDATE INTERVAL IS NOT COMPLETED.

THE SERVICE IS NOT BIND IT'S EXTENDS WITH Service not with IntentService and added with statement as START_STICKY; as because I want this service to be run continuously

thanks!

Comment: after how much time you are getting update when you remove app from system tray??

Comment: I needs to start the app again....